# When performing mmap, would C or Java have any significant performance differences?

Tags: java, c, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I have a 50GB file that is a sorted csv file.

Would it in theory make any difference if I was performing lookups on this file using memory mapped access using C or java?

I'm guessing since the file access is pushed down to the operating system level, it really shouldn't make much of a difference correct?

Answer (score 2):

In *theory*, Java will be infinitesimally slower because of the need for additional indirections due to Java's object-oriented method invocation, and possibly due to the need to cross the Java/JNI boundary.

In *practice*, the Hotspot compiler optimizes direct ByteBuffer access, and the cost of page faults will far exceed the extra memory indirection.

Comment: And as a comment, I would transform the CSV into a fixed-length binary format for use.

Comment: Can java perform a memory mapped file that is larger than 10GB?  any restrictions?

Comment: @user1361315 - You may need to use the `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize` option (eg: `-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=64g`. This is used as an internal trigger for garbage collection of mapped buffers. I'm not sure which versions require it; definitely 1.6, and I'd expect 1.7 as well.

Comment: @user1361315 You need 10GB of address space to map a 10GB file.  32-bit machines usually have less than 2GB of address space available, so you'd need to add logic to only mmap a small piece of the file at a time.  If running on 32-bit operating system is part of your project's requirements, you absolutely need to test on such an OS.

Answer (score 1):

Giving a direct answer to question.

C's `mmap()` and Java's `FileChannel.map()` are considered to be pretty much equivalents and won't have significant performance differences.

Answer (score 1):

Java can only map 2 GB at a time.  This is because ByteBuffer uses 32-bit integers for length, size, etc.  So you'd need 25 mmaps for your 50 GB file.  C can just create a single mmap, although it won't be portable to 1990s computers (if you care about that)